# reformatting json using json_encode for a javascript var

Tags: php, javascript, json

quick question i really need some help, i re-formatting some json to get it into a javascript var, i got it working with json_encode but i need it to output ' symbol instead of the " symbol, is there a way to do that

i need it to be like this (using the ' symbol)

```
{
title:'Greeting',
mp3:'http://www.godsgypsychristianchurch.net/music/Atlanta%20GA/Dey%20duma%20amensa/01%20Greeting.mp3',
buy:'http://www.godsgypsychristianchurch.net/music/Atlanta%20GA/Dey%20duma%20amensa/01%20Greeting.mp3',
price:'Download',
duration:'',
cover:'http://godsgypsychristianchurch.net/music_artwork/DEFAULT_COVER.png'},
```

My Code:

```
foreach ($json['rows'] as $row) {
    if ($_GET['churchname'] == $row[doc]['album']) {
        $songCount = 0;
        foreach ($row['doc']['tracks'] as $song) {
            ++$songCount;
            $arr = array(
                "title" => "{$song['name']}",
                "mp3" => "{$songUrl}",
                "buy" => "{$songUrl}",
                "price" => "Download",
                "duration" => "",
                "cover" => "{$row['doc']['artwork']}",
                );
            echo json_encode($arr);
        }
    }
}
exit;
```

Comment: Can't you just search the result of `json_encode()` for double quotes and replace them with single quotes?

Answer (score 2):

1) You can't get it to use the `' '`, as the specification for valid-JSON requires `" "`, so any program expecting to parse your string from JSON to an object in JS/PHP/etc, is going to error out on you

2) Why? JS doesn't care which one you use, one way or another, and if you're doing something on the server-side, leave it as a multi-dimensional (potentially associative) array.

3) If it's for the purpose of including `" "` inside of your actual string, then escape them with `\`, like so:

```
$myString = "This is my \"double-quoted\" string";

$myString === 'This is my "double-quoted" string';
$myString === "This is my " . '"double-quoted"' . "string";
```

If you are concatenating strings together, and one of those strings already contains double-quotes within the string itself, then your language will automatically ensure they're escaped.

I'd be happy to help further, but I'd need to know the "Why?" part.

Comment: Thanks for that help, I did not know that I'll give it a shot when I get home, but just to give you a bit more info, here is what I am trying to accomplish but this version is hard coded (static) I'm trying to pull the data from my JSON http://ggcc.tv/NewSite/cities/atlanta/AllThingsArePossible.html you can view the page source and check it out, sorry I can paste the code in a comment and not to mention from my iPhone - thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, so first a very quick semantic thing: your `myPlaylist` variable isn't JSON - it's a JS array which holds JS objects. Normally, that sounds rather pedantic, I get that...  ...but here's why it's important: 1) JS accepts both `'` and `"`, while JSON accepts only `"` 2) JSON is a `string`: `"[\"one\",\"two\"]"` and is not an object or an array or anything else -- it's just a string that looks like one. The really, really easy solution here, seeing as you've already got `myPlaylist` written out, is to do something like `var json_playlist = JSON.stringify(myPlaylist);` then copy the string.

Comment: `myPlaylist` is perfectly-valid JS, so turning it into a JSON string is a snap. Then you just need to copy that string and that will become your JSON, which you can then `JSON.parse(json);` back into an object in JS, or `json_decode($json, true);` it into an associative array in PHP, or whatever languages it will be that you're going to use.